# Number of elements of numpy arrays inside specific bins

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an ensemble of **sorted** (one-dimensional) arrays of **unequal lengths** (say `M0`, `M1` and `M2`). I want to find **how many elements of each of these arrays is inside specific number ranges** (where the number ranges are specified by **neighboring elements from another sorted array**, say `zbin`). I want to know what is the **fastest way** to achieve this.

Here, I am giving a small example of the task that I want to do (and also the method that I am following presently to achieve the desired functionality):

```
""" Function to do search query """
def search(numrange, lst):
    arr = np.zeros(len(lst))        
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        probe = lst[i]
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(probe)):
            if (probe[j]>numrange[1]): break
            if (probe[j]>=numrange[0]) and (probe[j]<=numrange[1]): count = count + 1   

        arr[i] = count
    return arr


""" Some example of sorted one-dimensional arrays of unequal lengths """
M0 = np.array([5.1, 5.4, 6.4, 6.8, 7.9])
M1 = np.array([5.2, 5.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9.1, 9.2])
M2 = np.array([6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 7.2])

""" Implementation and output """
lst = [M0, M1, M2]
zbin = np.array([5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5])
zarr = np.zeros( (len(zbin)-1, len(lst)) )
for i in range(len(zbin)-1):
    numrange = [zbin[i], zbin[i+1]]
    zarr[i,:] = search(numrange, lst)

print zarr
```

**Output:**

```
[[ 2.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  3.]]
```

Here, the final output `zarr` gives me the number of elements of each of the arrays (`M0`, `M1` and `M2`) inside each of the bins possible from `zbin` (*viz.* `[5.0, 5.5]`, `[5.5, 6.0]` and `[6.0, 6.5]`.) For example consider the bin `[5.0, 5.5]`. The array `M0` has **2** elements inside that bin (`5.1` and `5.4`), `M1` has **1** element (`5.2`) and `M2` has **0** elements in that bin. This gives the first row of `zarr` i.e. `[2,1,0]`. One can get the other rows of `zarr` in a similar manner.

In my actual task, I will be dealing with `zbin` of lengths much larger than what I have given in this example, and also bigger and many more arrays like `M0`, `M1`, `...` `Mn`. All `M`s and the array `zbin` would be sorted always. I am wondering if the function that I have designed (`search()`), and the method that I am following are the most optimum and the **fastest** ways to achieve the desired functionality. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: How many arrays would there in that list, typically? Would those arrays be always sorted?

Comment: @Divakar : There are about 1000 such arrays (`M` ). They would be sorted always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could make use of the sorted nature and hence use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) for this task, like so -

```
out = np.empty((len(zbin)-1, len(lst)),dtype=int)
for i,l in enumerate(lst):
    left_idx = np.searchsorted(l, zbin[:-1], 'left')
    right_idx = np.searchsorted(l, zbin[1:], 'right')
    out[:,i] = right_idx - left_idx
```

Comment: Divakar:  This is a great way to achieve the desired task. Many thanks. :-D

Comment: @Sidd ?? Can't understand, why you now accept a self coded answer... IMHO is this shoud be slower than calling np.histogram, right? Not want to offend you, Divakar, but this should be at least evaluated. I would have expected Ethans answer to be accepted, no?

Comment: @SpghttCd I would encourage OP to evaluate, or at least I would hope they do.

Comment: @SpghttCd : I was waiting for someone to that put that as an answer. Maybe you can do that. I would like to accept one answer.

Comment: :-) come on, putting np.histogram in a loop over your Arrays is so unbelievable simple, that you can accept Ethans answer already. Ok, it would be nice if there would be the code in the answer word by word, but - well just look in my first comment under it. He was just faster than me, so I will not post this solution as an answer here.

Comment: @SpghttCd: Sorry for the multitude of comments. I find that Divakar's method is faster than np.histogram (at least for the number of `M` arrays that I am working with). You can also test it if you like. I think the reason is because Divakar's method is exploiting the sorted nature of the arrays. At the same time, I very much appreciate the gesture (not posting the solution.) Big thanks to all three: Divakar, Ethan and you. :-)

Comment: @SiddTheKid Appreciate that you have timed it!

Comment: Divakar: Your answers are always fantastic kind of awesome. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Very interesting and good to know, as I definitely didn't expect that - and right: very good, that you tested it! - So of course +1

Comment: Divakar: Can I use this solution for a slightly different case, where all `M` are sorted but `zbin` is not sorted?

Comment: Divakar: My new `zbin` is of this form now `zbin = [5.0, 5.2, 5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 5.4]`. So, now the first bin is `[5.0, 5.2]`, second bin is `[5.1, 5.3]` and so on. What should I do here?

Comment: @SiddTheKid Well, I think the code won't change. As long as the arrays in that list `lst` are sorted, it should be good. Can you check?

Comment: Divakar: Maybe, I am not defining the new bins properly. I will think a little bit and then comment maybe. Thanks again for the help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it would be difficult to beat the performance of simply looping over each array and calling numpy.histogram.  I’m guessing you haven’t tried this or you’d have mentioned it!

It’s certainly possible that you could exploit the sorted nature to come up with a faster solution, but I’d start by comparing the timing of that.

Comment: @SiddTheKid Just try `for m in [M0, M1, M2]: print(np.histogram(m, zbin)[0])`     I'd be especially interested in the difference of the output to your output. i.e.: How do you Count the values which are in your bins? Because the output of np.histogram is clear for me... `[2 0 1]
[1 1 0]
[0 0 3]`

Comment: @Ethan: One place where I am exploiting the sorted nature of the arrays `M` is in this line: `if (probe[j]>numrange[1]): break`.

Comment: @SpghttCd: The said method: `for m in [M0, M1, M2]: print(np.histogram(m, zbin))` gives me slightly different answer than what I desire.  The difference may be slight (`+/- 1`), but it will significantly affect some further investigations that I haven't mentioned here.

Comment: @SiddTheKid Right, but can you explain, what I'm not getting here? E.g. Where in M2 is the 1 value which falls into the first bin between 5.0 and 5.5?

Comment: @SpghttCd: For example consider bin `[5.0, 5.5]`. The array `M0` has **2** elements inside that bin (`5.1` and `5.4`),  `M1` has **1** element (`5.2`) and `M2` has **0** elements in that bin. This gives the first row of `zarr` *i.e.* `[2,1,0]`. One can get the other rows of `zarr` in a similar manner.

Comment: @SiddTheKidd Ah, lol! Then np.histogram just gives you the transposed result. What you have in columns can be found there in rows.

Comment: @SpghttCd: Oh yes, wonder how I missed that! What you have describe is a great way! Thanks again. :-D

Comment: @SiddTheKidd Yes, your task is just exactly the job of np.histogram.