# How many elements of numpy array in specified number range

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a list of **sorted** numpy arrays of **unequal** lengths (say `M0`, `M1`, `M2`) I want to find how many elements of each of these arrays is inside number ranges which are given by a adjoining pairs of an array (say `zbin`. `zbin` is **not sorted** and the said number ranges are like the following `[z[0], z[1]]`, `[z[2], z[3]]`, `[z[4], z[5]]` and so on. `zbin` always has an even number of elements. ) The **unsorted nature** of `zbin` and the consideration of **adjoining pairs** for in `zbin` for finding the number ranges makes this question different from the one asked here [Number of elements of numpy arrays inside specific bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362479/number-of-elements-of-numpy-arrays-inside-specific-bins) . In the said link, `zarr` was **sorted** and *adjoining elements* gave number ranges (here *adjoining pairs* give number ranges).

This is what I am doing presently:

```
""" Function to do search query """
def search(numrange, lst):
    arr = np.zeros(len(lst))        
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        probe = lst[i]
        count = 0
        for j in range(len(probe)):
            if (probe[j]>numrange[1]): break
            if (probe[j]>=numrange[0]) and (probe[j]<=numrange[1]): count = count + 1   

        arr[i] = count
    return arr


""" Some example of sorted one-dimensional arrays of unequal lengths """
M0 = np.array([5.1, 5.4, 6.4, 6.8, 7.9])
M1 = np.array([5.2, 5.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9.1, 9.2])
M2 = np.array([6.1, 6.2, 6.5, 7.2])

""" Implementation and output """
lst = [M0, M1, M2]
zbin = np.array([5.0, 5.2, 5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 5.4])

zarr = np.zeros( (len(zbin)/2, len(lst)) )
for i in np.arange(0, len(zbin)/2, 1):
    indx = i*2
    print indx
    numrange = [zbin[indx], zbin[indx+1]]
    zarr[i,:] = search(numrange, lst)

print zarr
```

The **output** is:

```
[[ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.]]
```

Here, the first row of `zarr` (`[1,1,0]` shows that `M0` has **1** element in the considered number range `[5.0, 5.2]`, `M1` has **1** element and `M2` has **0** elements. The second and the third rows show results for the subsequent number ranges, *i.e.* `[5.1, 5.3]` and `[5.2, 5.4]`.)

I want to know what is the fastest way to achieve this desired functionality (`zarr`). In my actual task, I will be dealing with `zbin` of much bigger size, and many more arrays (`M`). I will very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `out[::2]` from the accepted soln of the linked previous question of yours?

Comment: Or to save on memory, initialize with `out = np.empty((len(zbin)//2, len(lst)),dtype=int)` and then use `zbin[:-1:2]` and `zbin[1::2]` to get those left, right indices?

Comment: Divakar: As like all times, this is a great answer! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure numpy would really get you any speed up, but here's an attempt:

```
lst = [M0, M1, M2]
zbin = np.array([5.0, 5.2, 5.1, 5.3, 5.2, 5.4])

zarr = np.zeros((len(zbin)//2, len(lst)), dtype=np.float)

for i,M in enumerate(lst):
    zarr[:,i] = np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(M >= zbin[::2, np.newaxis],
                                                M <= zbin[1::2, np.newaxis]), axis=1)

In [10]: zarr
Out[10]: 
array([[1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0.]])
```

By the way, if you can exploit the sorted nature of the arrays, @Divakar solution from the linked question should definitely be faster.

Comment: filippo: Thanks for this very nice answer! This works and the speed is as per my requirements. :)